# Kotlin inline extension function on an imported java class

Tags: java, kotlin, extension-methods, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I have a backend Springboot kotlin project built with gradle. I'm importing a number of java libraries. My target JVM is 11

I tried to write an inline reified extension function for one of the imported classes and got a compiler error "Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 11 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.8"

Am I correct in understanding that the imported jar was built with JVM 1.8 and there isn't much I can do here?

Comment: Have you set Kotlin’s compile target? It’s 1.8 by default.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have, I've changed it to 11. Which is why, as far as I understand, the error tells me that my inline function is being compiled with JVM target 11